# KQL query to get the node count of running Aks clusters in azure

Tags: azure, azure-aks, kql, azure-resource-graph

I am new to Kusto. I need an query to get the current node count of all the running Azure kubernetes clusters. I have tried with below but for few clusters it is giving node count 0 where as mode is present on those

```
Resources
| where type == "microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters"
| extend nodepools = properties.agentPoolProfiles
| mv-expand nodepools
| project name, nodepools.name, nodepools.vmSize, nodepools.minCount, nodepools.maxCount, nodepools.powerState.code,nodeCount = tostring(nodepools['count'])
| sort by name
```

Comment: Are the clusters in a stopped state where the node count is displayed as 0?

Comment: No, they are running. Node is also in ready state.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get the node count of all the running Azure Kubernetes clusters in azure using the  Azure Resource Graph Explorer by using the below query and got the results successfully as shown in the below image:

```
Resources
 | where type == "microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters"
 | extend properties.agentPoolProfiles
 | project subscriptionId, name, pool = (properties.agentPoolProfiles)
 | mv-expand pool
 | project subscription = subscriptionId, cluster = name, size = pool.vmSize, count = pool.['count']
```

[image]

If any of the Kubernetes service cluster is in stopped state then it's node count will be shown as "0" as shown in the below image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried your query, still it is giving the same result, I mean some cluster's nodepool has running nodes but node count is showing 0. Not sure where the problem is.